# CSS filling a td with grating

Tags: css

I have in HTML + CSS the following structure:

[image]

You can see a working snippet here:

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{    
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.red{
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.orange{
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"></td>
        <td class="yellow"></td>
        <td class="orange"></td>
        <td class="blue"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to fill one square like this:

[image: Nedded]

Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: not clear how you need to feel the square

Comment: I guess you need square shape, without changing HTML structure (adding of rows)?

Comment: Edit post, what you need?

Comment: Post edited. What I needed was not published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a repeating linear gradient for that.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding:44px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.red {
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.yellow {
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.orange {
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.blue {
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
.grating{
    background-color:#269;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
        transparent, 
        transparent 10px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 10px, 
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 20px
    );
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td class="yellow"></td>
    <td class="orange"></td>
    <td class="blue"></td>
    <td class="grating"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use svg

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{    
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.red{
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.orange{
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
svg{
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-top:-21px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"></td>
        <td class="yellow"></td>
        <td class="orange"><svg width="40" height="40"><path d="m 0 20 l 20 -20 20 0 -40 40 0 20 60 -60" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
            </svg>
        </td>
        <td class="blue"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```